# Jolt nested array transformation

Tags: java, json, jolt

I'm a beginner in jolt transformations and I'm having below input payload that needs to be transformed before sending out

1. i want to create separate node based on nested array values and insert it back into array and remove the nested array completely from the output

```json
{
  "Def": {
    "capacity": {
      "accounttype": {
        "value": "customer"
      },
      "customer": {
        "name": "abc"
      },
      "config": [
        {
          "restriction": {
            "value": "inbound"
          },
          "serviceConfig": [
            {
              "serviceType": {
                "value": "standard"
              }
            },
            {
              "serviceType": {
                "value": "special"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and expected output is below

```json
{
  "Def": {
    "capacity": {
      "accounttype": {
        "value": "customer"
      },
      "customer": {
        "name": "abc"
      },
      "config": [
        {
          "restriction": {
            "value": "inbound"
          },
          "serviceType": {
            "value": "standard"
          }
        },
        {
          "restriction": {
            "value": "inbound"
          },
          "serviceType": {
            "value": "special"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I did try multiple things but none of them seems to work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation spec in which walk through the indexes of `serviceConfig` array and then tile the other elements by using  `"*": "&2.&1.&"` (*as else case*) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Def": {
        "capacity": {
          "*": "&2.&1.&", // &2 stands for going the tree 2 levels up and grabbing the value "Def", &1 for "capacity", & as leaf node which copies the current node's value
          "config": {
            "*": {
              "serviceConfig": {
                "*": {
                  "@(2,restriction)": "&6.&5.&4[&1].restriction", 
                  "*": "&6.&5.&4[&1].&" // &6 -> "Def", &5 -> "capacity", &4 -> "config", [&1] -> indexes of serviceConfig, & -> leaf node which copies the current node's value
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]